# Solutions to equations generated from a set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

For a finite set of polynomials $\{f_1(x), f_2(x),\dots , f_n(x)\}$ of degree 4, I'm trying to find the set of all possible roots of the equations in the form $$
\pm f_1(x)\pm f_2(x)\pm\cdots \cdots f_n(x)=0.
$$
Is there a way of describing this set given a particular set of polynomials?

Comment: You don't assume that the polynomials $f_k$ have a same degree ? You consider as well real and complex roots ?

Comment: Yes, they are of the same degree.

Comment: You haven't answered about complex roots ? Do you consider them ?

Comment: You have (at most) $2^{n-1}$ (at most) quartic equations, which you can solve and find the roots. If that's not what you are after then you should explain what "*describing this set*" means here.

Comment: Yes, I consider complex roots.

Comment: Right, but the number of roots is << $2^(n-1)$, so i'm curious if there is a concise way of doing so. For instance, in the simplest case I get 14 different equations, but only 5 distinct roots.

Comment: @voligno Not sure what you call "*the simplest case*". You can have between $1$ and $4 \cdot 2^{n−1}$ distinct roots, and that's all you can say about it in general.

Comment: @dxiv I'm sorry I can't state the problem in a clearer way. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you should say is why you are interested in this problem ? This kind of information helps rather often...